# Pagespeed problem when typic in URL: "The referrer https://www.googleapis.com/ does not match the referrer restrictions configured on your API key."

Tags: google-api, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

Anyone know what this means? I went to https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftreepi.me%2F and I am given this error. It was working yesterday. I have no idea what is going on. It's just a WordPress blog with Google Site Kit enabled. I've removed and reinstalled Site Kit, but still same issue.

> The referrer https://www.googleapis.com/ does not match the referrer
>   restrictions configured on your API key. Please use the API Console to
>   update your key restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

This is normally caused by some sort of firewall issue / browser extension blocking referrer on requests.

Last couple of times I have seen this error someone was using Brave Browser with 'shields up'.

I ran it fine so try a different browser / incognito mode and see if that helps.